# VMware to Azure Site Recovery; disable replication failed:

Tags: azure, vmware-vsphere, replication

I have a VM that I am replicating to Azure from a VMWare host. I needed to change the hard drive type to SSD Premium, and so started a disable replication, so that I could re-replicate. The disable replication failed, and now the server is stuck in limbo. It is not replicating and and I can't re-replicate because it is still in Azure Site Recovery. Has anyone dealt with something like this? I need to remove it or get replication working again.